# Is it possible to make the variable inside nested for loop local

Tags: shell, variable

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in  1 2 3 4
do

#   {
#   local i     ##gives error  local: can only be used in a function
    for i in 1 2 3
    do
    echo "inner loop ----- $i"
    (( i++ ))
    done
#   }
echo $i
done
```

outout :

```
inner loop ----- 1
inner loop ----- 2
inner loop ----- 3
4
inner loop ----- 1
inner loop ----- 2
inner loop ----- 3
4
inner loop ----- 1
inner loop ----- 2
inner loop ----- 3
4
inner loop ----- 1
inner loop ----- 2
inner loop ----- 3
4
```

Is it possible to make the variable inside nested for loop local.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you run the inner variable in a sub shell, it will not affect the outer variable:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4; do
    (
        for i in 1 2 3; do
            echo "inner loop ----- $i"
            (( i++ ))
        done
    )
    echo $i
done
```

Which results in:

```
inner loop ----- 1
inner loop ----- 2
inner loop ----- 3
1
inner loop ----- 1
inner loop ----- 2
inner loop ----- 3
2
inner loop ----- 1
inner loop ----- 2
inner loop ----- 3
3
inner loop ----- 1
inner loop ----- 2
inner loop ----- 3
4
```

Comment: This is valid, but please don't. It makes this much harder to read at a glance.

Comment: Abusing subshells too much could make a script noticeably slower.

Comment: But it is harder to read only to those people who don't abuse subshells.

Answer (score 16):

> Is it possible to make the variable inside nested for loop local.

Yes, but only using a function.

As the builtin `local` can only exist inside a function, we need to provide a function to make the variable `i` change the scope from global to local:

```
#!/bin/bash

internalfunction () {
    local i     ### Works as is inside a function
    for i in 1 2 3; do
        echo "inner loop ----- $i"
        (( i++ ))
    done
}

for i in  1 2 3 4; do
    echo $i
    internalfunction
done
```

---

```
$ ./script.sh
1
inner loop ----- 1
inner loop ----- 2
inner loop ----- 3
2
inner loop ----- 1
inner loop ----- 2
inner loop ----- 3
3
inner loop ----- 1
inner loop ----- 2
inner loop ----- 3
4
inner loop ----- 1
inner loop ----- 2
inner loop ----- 3
```

Comment: Also valid, and much easier to read.

Comment: just noticed that using just { } makes the variables local.declareing the var using `declare` also makes it local

Comment: @munish No, only `{ }` is not enough. Yes, declare makes a var local *Inside a function*.